# Recursion on array of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I am learning how to recursively process arrays of arrays. For example, my program takes N strings as an input. Then I build a function `rev_print` that should print it again but from the end!

```
#include<stdio.h>
void rev_print(char **, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Parametri - argc = %d\n", argc);
    int i;
    printf("%s\n\n", argv[0]);

for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    printf("\n");

    rev_print(argv, argc);

    return 0;
}

/********** AUX ************/   

void rev_print(char **p, int n){    /*It should print the array backwards*/
    static int i = 0;
    if(n >= 2){
        rev_print(p, n - 1);
        ++i;
        printf("%s\n", *(p + i));
    }
    else
        printf("%s", *(p + n));
}
```

I tried anything I know, but at this point I am afraid I do now know recursion. `print_rev` will print the array in the regular order.

I have an hypothesis, that is, my function is not actually changing the memory locations of the strings. Am I correct?

On linux, I run the program with:

```
./myProgram.x It is a beautiful day
```

Comment: In the command `./myProgram.x < It is a beautiful day`, the `<` will be captured by the shell and interpreted as a redirection. Don't use it.

Comment: As for your problem, start with the call `rev_print(argv, argc - 1)` and then print `p[n]` and call recursively with `n - 1` as long as `n >= 0`. It's much simpler than you made it, and you don't need static variables.

Comment: `&(*p)` is an interesting way to write `p`.

Comment: Your problem is you're kind of reversing twice. Your recursive calls indeed print in reversed order, but you take the last element in each step.

Comment: a very simple implementation would be `void rev_print(char **argv){ if (*argv) { rev_print(argv+1); puts(*argv); } }`.

Comment: Side note to preempt future problems: Don't use `static` variable `i` to hold the recursion depth. Pass the recursion depth as a parameter instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these valuable suggestions. I am figuring out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion to print a list in reverse order is much simpler than you have coded. In a nutshell, printing the list in reverse order using recursion works like this:

1. If the list has more than one item, ignore the first item and print in reverse order the rest of the list.
2. Print the first item.

Step #1 is the recursion step. Printing the rest of the list invokes the same function with different arguments. It is important to check the ending condition to avoid entering an infinite recursion. Call the function recursively only if there is a "rest of the list" to print.

Coding it is as simple as this:

```
void rev_print(char **p, int n)
{
   # 1. Ignore the first item, recursively print the rest of the list, if any
   if (n > 1) {
        rev_print(p + 1, n - 1);
   }

   # 2. Print the first item 
   printf("%s\n", *p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a recursive solution, one fruitful approach is often to begin by thinking about how the problem to be solved can be split into smaller and simpler subproblems.

One way of thinking about the problem of printing a list of strings in reverse is to consider that, given such a list, the list can be split into the first string and a list of the remaining strings. Now the list of remaining strings needs to be printed in reverse, after which the first string should be printed. When the list of strings is empty, there is nothing to reverse and nothing to print.

Here is an example `rev_print()` function. Here `str_list` is an array of pointers to `char`, which is terminated with a null pointer. Note that `argv` is such an array, and this is a convenient way to control iteration over the array.

```
void rev_print(char **str_list)
{
    if (*str_list) {
        rev_print(str_list + 1);    // reverse print the rest of the list
        puts(*str_list);            // print the first string
    }
}
```

If it is desired to reverse-print both the list of strings, and the characters within each string, the same approach can be applied. A function, such as `rev_print_string()`, can be written that splits a string into its first character and the remaining characters. The remaining characters are printed in reverse, after which the first character is printed. When the string is empty, there are no characters to reverse and print.

This function can be used in a `rev_rev_print()` function, similar to `rev_print()`. The only difference here is that instead of printing the strings with `puts()`, the strings are printed with `rev_print()`. Note that the `rev_print()` function does not print a newline character, so this is printed in `rev_rev_print()` after reverse-printing a string.

Here is a complete example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rev_print(char **str_list);
void rev_rev_print(char **str_list);
void rev_print_string(char *str);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        puts(argv[i]);
    }

    char **strings = argv + 1;

    putchar('\n');
    rev_print(strings);

    putchar('\n');
    rev_rev_print(strings);

    return 0;
}

void rev_print(char **str_list)
{
    if (*str_list) {
        rev_print(str_list + 1);    // reverse print the rest of the list
        puts(*str_list);            // print the first string
    }
}

void rev_rev_print(char **str_list)
{
    if (*str_list) {
        rev_rev_print(str_list + 1);   // reverse-reverse print remainder
        rev_print_string(*str_list);   // reverse print the first string
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void rev_print_string(char *str)
{
    if (*str) {
        rev_print_string(str + 1);   // reverse print remainder of string
        putchar(*str);               // print the first character
    }
}
```

And here is a sample interaction:

```
λ> ./reverse It is a beautiful day
It
is
a
beautiful
day

day
beautiful
a
is
It

yad
lufituaeb
a
si
tI
```